# Can I call the function 'main' more than once in a program?

Tags: python, program-entry-point

I am writing a program that has user enter selections in a command line GUI and do not want the program to end until the user selects 'Exit'.

So far, my only solution is to end the workhorse function with a call to 'main()' so as to not exit out.

```
def parse(file):
    out_file = functions(file)
    main()

def get_selection():
    return selection

def main():
    file_to_parse = get_selection()
    parse(file_to_parse)
    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

My code runs and no other considerations are needed at this time in regards to time or security. I am just wondering how gross of a programming error/mistake/bad opinion I am making.

Comment: You should use a [`while` loop](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WhileLoop) to repeat things until a condition is met.

Answer (score 1):

```
def parse(file):
    out_file = functions(file)

def get_selection():
    return selection

def main():
    file_to_parse = get_selection()
    while file_to_parse.lower() != 'exit':
        parse(file_to_parse)
        file_to_parse = get_selection()
    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

May be something like this would work. Check out looping and strings in Python.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a while loop. But your solution works right?

Comment: Since it's Python, in theory, the original solution does not work, because it will fail upon reaching the recursion depth limit. Otherwise, it's just ugly.

Comment: Yes. The solution works. But calling main() a second time feels so very, very wrong. By **while loop** you mean a loop in the main func?

Comment: @SiliWili why does it feel "wrong"? It is a valid solution, if you don't think you will need to recurse more than a few hundred times. A while-loop will probably be more straightforward than recursion. But there is nothing inherently wrong with recursive functions. Also, `main` has no special status in Python. It is just a name you've decided to give to a function.